# About checking whether a client is disconnected from the Server Socket

Tags: java, sockets, socket.io

From (**Java Network Programming fourth edition**):
To tell if a socket is currently open, you need to
check that `isConnected()` returns true and `isClosed()` returns false. For an example:

```
boolean connected = socket.isConnected() && ! socket.isClosed();
```

I need to find a way to discover as soon as possible that the client has disconnected from the Server Socket. Using the trick described above,I have tried the following :

```
    Socket socket = ...;
    while (socket.isConnected() && !socket.isClosed()) {
      // do something ...
      // here, the client is always connected   
     }
    // client is disconnected
```

The above approach works for me, but it is always correct?. it detects all the cases?

Comment: what happened if when you are inside the while loop, you get disconnected from server?

Comment: Isn't `while ( !socket.isClosed() && socket.isConnected()) {` better

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969866/java-detect-lost-connection

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the application, catching exceptions intelligently would seem like a good solution. The requirement, however, is that you actually wants to send/do something to the client. Possibly a combination of the two approaches suits your specific application. You could try seeing:
[Java detect lost connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969866/java-detect-lost-connection)

Answer (score 0):

The book is wrong, if that's what it really says. `isConnected()` has nothing to do with whether a socket is currently open. It tells you whether it has ever been connected, which is not at all the same thing.

`isOpen()` does tell you whether the *socket* is open, but that doesn't tell you anything about the state of the *connection.* The test for whether the connection is still open is whether:

- `read()` has returned -1
- `readLine()` has returned null
- `readXXX()` has thrown `EOFException` for any other X

... all of which indicate that the peer has closed the connection, or

- any read or write method has thrown an `IOException` with the text 'connection reset'.