# Android,Java,socket, determine remote host disconnect

Tags: java, android, sockets, block

I'm trying to code a TCP client in android java. Most works fine. But i have one issue. If the socket is connected and the remeote host shuts down or the network goes down or something else, the socket.getinputstream keeps blocking.

I don't know if the socket is still connected. I code in objective-c too and in objective-c i get an event that the socket forcefully shuts down and i can try to reconnect. So on objective c the socket tracks the state.

In java the socket and the inputstream is still connected or blocked even the socket is down. How can i check if the socket is still connected?

```
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
                    String host = params[0];
                    int port = Integer.parseInt(params[1]);
                    SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
                    Socket socket = new Socket();
                    socket.connect(sockaddr,5000);
                    socket.setSoTimeout(7000);

                    out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                    mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    while (mRun) {
                        try {
             ----->         mServerMessage = mBufferIn.readLine();
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            Log.d("my","hier3" + e.getMessage());
                        }
                        if (mServerMessage.trim() != null) {

                                sender.messageReceived(s2);

                             }else{

                            }

                        }

                    }

                } catch (UnknownHostException e

) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The question of how to **detect if the remote peer/socket has closed the connection** has been [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240694/java-socket-api-how-to-tell-if-a-connection-has-been-closed) as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969866/java-detect-lost-connection).
Basically, the answers suggest that you attempt to read from the socket, and then observe what happens (`read()` returns `-1`, or `readLine()` returns `null` or your read methods raise `EOFException`.