# In Android how can I receive an event when my socket closes or disconnects?

Tags: android, sockets, tcp

I'm investigating a problem when my Android device gets disconnected from a PC it talks to after 1 minute of inactivity.  The PC receives a "disconnected" error from Winsock.    But on the Android I don't know anything is wrong unless I try to send something.  All the power-saving sleep and timeout features on the Android device are disabled - the network, wifi, screen, etc are set to stay awake forever.

My Android code uses a standard java.net.Socket.  It initializes without incident . . .

```
  try {
    sock = new Socket(configLGIP, 180 + SafeActivity.pdanum);
    Integer iPDANum = SafeActivity.pdanum + 180;
```

...after initialization I sent a "what's up" message to the PC . . .

```
    if (sock != null) try {
      sock.setTcpNoDelay(true);  //Make steer smooth
      bin = new BufferedInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
      out = new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), "US-ASCII");

      //say hello to the front end
      cmdBuf = new String(new StringBuilder("(WhatsUp,").append(session).append(",").append(sSerialNum).append(",SupportsDebulk").append(")").toString());
      out.write(cmdBuf, 0, cmdBuf.length());
      out.flush();
      break;  
. . .
```

After that it happily sends packets, unless I do nothing for a minute in which case when I try to send a packet the Android sends (as seen from Wireshark...)

> 0.728561  10.1.2.1    10.1.2.11   TCP   74   53935→181 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=146600337 TSecr=0 WS=64

The code on the PC is written in Visual Basic by another programmer (I don't know VB) but **he can register for an error** and thus get notified when the connection is closed, and this code gets called shortly after the 1 minute is up...  **NB** - this code gets called without my having to do anything on the Android side -  just disconnecting the PC's CAT-5 cable from the WAP is sufficient

```
Private Sub winPocRem_Error(Index As Integer, ByVal Number As Integer, Description As String, ByVal sCode As Long, ByVal Source As String, ByVal HelpFile As String, ByVal HelpContext As Long, CancelDisplay As Boolean)

    If (Index = socket_intMax) Then

        'trace error
        Call TraceSocket("TCP socket(" & socket_intMax & ") Err=" & Number & ",Desc=" & Description, INBOUND)
        'reset status
```

This is called automagically as an event - he doesn't have to explicitly poll anything.

So how do I do something similar in Android, where I can be notified by an event if my connection is closed?   I'm a little embarrassed that I don't know how do do something in Android that can be done easily in VB.

**EDIT:**  One of the curious quirks of this is that if the PC tries to send a packet to the Android device and the Android responds with RST, the PC can still "ping" the Android device.   "ping" is ICMP.  UDP also still works.  Infact one thing we can do when the TCP connection goes away is send a message to the PC via UDP telling it that our TCP connection is not working.

Comment: API level 26 will introduce Java's asynchronous channels that have callbacks for IO events. Until then you can using SelectableChannels to monitor IO, but that will feel more like polling.

Comment: Aren't  "channels" sub-TCP?      One of the curious quirks of this is that if the PC tries to send a packet to the Android device and the Android responds with [RST], but the PC can still "ping" the Android device.   "ping" is ICMP.  UDP also still works.  Infact one thing we can do when the TCP connection goes away is send a message to the PC via UDP telling it that our TCP connection is not working.  (I'll add this detail to the question)